# problems using the Android Studio emulator with Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

[when i try to emulate my flutter project i get this message, does anyone know what to do? When emulating in Android Studio some project with Kotlin works perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVn2i.png)

Comment: Can you try to run from shell `flutter run --verbose`? On your screenshot of error, problem with app build, not in emulator (Gradle error relatives to Android build).

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should check `buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"`. The version might be different but there would be buildToolsVersion, note down the version and check if it is installed or update/upgrade it from file > Project Structure